# React component library with two different design systems with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, git, styled-components

I have a react component library implemented with styled components. Long story short, the company changed it's design system and they decided they need both styling, old and new, to be available for different projects(no runtime switching). So for now, we have two versions of the library, on two main branches of the same project, the difference being in the styled components files.

The problem is that new components or fixes need to be implemented in both versions, and what we are doing now is manually syncing the branches for the behavioral part of the components, but this task is becoming harder and harder to handle.

Some of the ideas were splitting the library in two, old and new, but doesn't solve the syncing problem; or splitting into three, behavioral, old style, and new style, and the behavioral library should somehow (don' know how) use one or the other; or let the app switch between the styled components at runtime, but that seems to add unnecessary complexity; or switching back to sass instead of styled components and let the user app choose which sass file will load (but I would be really sad to give up on the styled components).

Any ideas, advice, warnings, been-there-done-that-ers? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try something like this: [React Theme Management in Less with Javascript](https://medium.com/hootsuite-engineering/react-theme-management-in-less-with-javascript-4b64cbd5eb15)? Or perhaps even: [Theming in React with Styled Components](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/creating-themes-in-react-with-styled-components-6fce744b4e54).

To me it seems like it isn't so much about splitting up the library into different components (which can get super messy over time). Rather it would be more about finding a way to make the styling abstract in such a way that you have different themes (Old Theme vs New Theme) and can choose either one as you use the library for other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I really love theme management in styled-components. I believe this approach would make switching themes a breeze. Let me try to explain with a simple example.

Step 1 - Use a theme-file with e.g. theme_one.js and theme_two.js.

```
    const theme_one = {
       primary: "hsl(233, 26%, 24%)",
       secondary: "hsl(136, 65%, 51%)",
      };

    const theme_two = {
       primary: "hsl(024, 16%, 4%)",
       secondary: "hsl(112, 25%, 81%)",
      };
```

Step 2 - Import the relevant theme into your root App Component and then use the ThemeProvider

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components"
```

as a context provider in your App.js. The following code will make that theme available in every child-component.

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme_one}>
  <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Step 3 - Access the theme in any downstream component:

```
const StyledComponent = styled.div`
background-color: ${props => props.theme.primary}`
```

With this method, you would need to plug in either theme_one or theme_two in your context provider and watch the beauty unfold.